# When using Linq, I want to carry headings into Gridview, without having to list each field

Tags: c#, linq, gridview, datatable

I am trying to bind a filtered csv file to a datatable.
I use a Linq query to find selected fields (originaly from checkboxes). 
Then I am using a foreach loop to load the query to a datadatbale.
Lastly bind to a gridview.

The problem I am having is carrying the column headings into a Gridview.
When I used ADO I could inherit the the first row with the headings.

With the following Linq code, I have to list each column. 
There are over 200 fields and it causes me to do more data cleanup.
Is there a way to do this without having to list each field?  Thanks

```
            var FilterDetail = from FilterDetailTable in dTable10.AsEnumerable()
                               from filters in dTableFilters.AsEnumerable()
                               where (filters.Field<string>("FilterParm") ==  FilterDetailTable.Field<string>("Status"))
                               select FilterDetailTable;


            foreach (var FilterDetailTable2 in FilterDetail)
            {
                dTable10_Filtered.ImportRow(
                FilterDetailTable2
                );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you enable auto generate columns on the grid?

Comment: I found my problem. I needed to add the columns before I did the foreach loop.  Sorry I missed that.  Thanks for your fast response.